# Как в XML форме (Qt Designer ) заменить класс QLabel на ExtendedQLabel для PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, ui, pyqt4

Как в Qt Designer заменить класс QLabel на ExtendedQLabel для PyQt5?

ExtendedQLabel.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


class ExtendedQLabel(QLabel):

    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init(self, parent):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        QLabel.mouseReleaseEvent(self, e)
        self.clicked.emit()
```

В Qt Designer делаю так:
[image: Qt Designer]

Вот XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>570</width>
    <height>462</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>335</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>371</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>350</x>
     <y>410</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>460</x>
     <y>410</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="ExtendedQLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>311</width>
     <height>301</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>TextLabel</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>ExtendedQLabel</class>
   <extends>QLabel</extends>
   <header location="global">extendedqlabel</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А все, понял, надо было делать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]